# What does the .0 and .1 mean Swift 3.0.1

Tags: swift, tuples

Hello i was wondering what does the .0 and .1 do, or means at somepoint constant y know it is the x and y axis, but what does the .0 and .1 do?

```
let somePoint = (1, 1)
switch somePoint {
case (0, 0):
    print("(0, 0) is at the origin")
case (_, 0):
    print("(\(somePoint.0), 0) is on the x-axis")
case (0, _):
    print("(0, \(somePoint.1)) is on the y-axis")
case (-2...2, -2...2):
    print("(\(somePoint.0), \(somePoint.1)) is inside the box")
default:
    print("(\(somePoint.0), \(somePoint.1)) is outside of the box")
}
// Prints "(1, 1) is inside the box"
```

Comment: I would highly recommend reading the [tuples section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329) of the language guide.

Comment: You are declaring a (Int, Int) tuple. It doesn't intrinsically have anything to do with x or y like calling let somePoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0) would. So the .0 means the first or zeroth element of the tuple and .1 means the second element.

Comment: From the Language Guide: *Alternatively, access the individual element values in a tuple using index numbers starting at zero*

Comment: Thank you to both for the help, it makes sence now, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.0` in `somePoint.0` is accessing the first element (at index 0) of the tuple `somePoint`. `.1` is accessing the second element (at index 1).

As others have pointed out, this is covered in the [**first** section of the language guide, "The Basics".](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329)

Comment: Thank you so much Alexander, it all makes sence now. Thank you.

Comment: i am reading it, but in the explanation it is not explained, at least not yet in Control Flow.

Comment: It's explained in "The Basics", which is the first section, even before "Control Flow".